# Does c++ std map's erase function free the memory of pointer key?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

In my application i am using c++ std map with **char *** as key. Here is the code example erasing data entry from map using iterator.

```
// map declaration in the code
map<VcmU8T*, time_t, DataMapStrCmpT> mDataMap;

auto it = mDataMap.find(apKey);
if (it != mDataMap.end()) {
    mDataMap.erase(it);
}
```

Does above code clears(free) the memory of the key pointer?

Comment: Why on earth would it?

Comment: Because while doing i got this error *** glibc detected *** /app/Code/feature-li/CppMap: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffffffdbb8 ***

Comment: Using pointer as key is suspicious, why not simply `std::map<std::string, time_t>` ?

Comment: @user2613486: The pointer could point to static memory, into a stack frame, into the midst of some allocated memory block, or other parts of the program might still hold references to that memory. Automatically deleting memory just because you remove a pointer to it form a container would be.... not good?

Comment: Also, I frown at your use of the word "free". In C++, memory is allocated with `new` and released with `delete`. Let's call your use of "free" in this context a... smell.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your key. You have memory corruption elsewhere. Valgrind is your friend.

Comment: Issue is resolved, i have created two key pointer with same key value, and instead of insert i used [] operator to insert/update operations, due to wrong key pointer used to find and erase the key and value. i got that error. thanks guys for your help

Comment: @user2613486 Having a `char*` as a key is not a good idea.  Basically all you did to "solve your problem" is to introduce more hard-to-maintain logic, which by your description, is still easily breakable.  A `std::map<std::string, time_t>` is the obvious, simple, workaround.

Answer (score 7):

No.

It [removes the specified element from the container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase). No more, no less.

Comment: but while doing so i got this error *** glibc detected *** /app/Code/feature-li/CppMap: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffffffdbb8 ***

Comment: @user2613486: Then post a different question containing a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) asking about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Does above code clears(free) the memory of the key pointer?

No.

You should use a **string class** (e.g. `std::string`) as key type, instead of a raw character pointer: In fact, using a string *class* guarantees *automatic* memory management (including memory cleanup) for the string key.